# Função qsort para ordenar uma struct

Tags: c, c++

```
typedef struct{
    long At[tam], Si[tam], Sf[tam];
}TDados;
```

Para esta `struct`, queria entender como ordenar a `struct` pelo Sf usando a função **qsort**. Será que alguém pode me explicar?

Comment: Precisaria estabelecer critérios, que dados seriam considerados para ordenar. Quer ordenar o `Sf` ou usar o `Sf` como chave de ordenação? Cadê o resto do código?